# In Textmate2, how do you disable the header-styles in Markdown documents?

Tags: macos, markdown, textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I am currently trying to disable or tweak the new "headline-style" that was introduced with TM2 (or the bundle?).

The undesired behaviour will change the font-size and family for the line depending on the headline level.

Here is an example output:

[image: markdown example with headlines]

I already tried to change themes and inspected the bundle sourcecode but i can't find anything related to this.

How can i disable/remove this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the `Bundles` menu, select `Edit Bundles…`.

Then select the bundle `Themes` and open the `Settings`.

There you can disable each `Markup: Heading #`, change the sizes or even delete them. (Remember to close and reopen your document for changes to apply)

Comment: Thank you! Somehow i didn't got any notification for your answer so i accepted a little late. sorry. This was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Hilton's TextMate 2 Bundle](https://github.com/hiltmon/hiltons-bundle) that overrides Markdown theme preferences and disables the "Baskerville" font for headers.

Also, be sure to check out [these posts](http://hiltmon.com/blog/categories/textmate/) on TextMate 2 by Hilton Lipschitz.